# Change UITableViewCell Font in iOS 8 and swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, cell

I'm trying to change the font for my uitableviewcells,

I'm trying to use this at the moment with not success:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont .preferredFontForTextStyle("Avenir")];
```

Now i've read a lot on this and it seems I should use this instead :

```
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: "Avenir" size:22];
```

Problem is fontWithName does not seem to exist in iOS 8

any ideas??

thanks

Comment: @Jp4Real your problem solved or not.?

Comment: Yup problem solved sorry for the long wait thanks a lot

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The thing is that this is not Swift (it is a kind of horrifying bastardization of Objective-C):

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: "Avenir" size:22];
```

This would be Swift:

```
cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:22)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following casting way:

```
cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size:22);
```